# SVG in HTML5 canvas element

Tags: html, svg, html5-canvas

How can I include a SVG image in a HTML5 canvas element, so that it also adjusts the size of the SVG when you change the size of the browser window?

Comment: *"[...] so that it also adjusts the size of the SVG when you change the size of the browser window"*: Do you know that a canvas does **not** resize automatically with the window?

Comment: Yes exactly. So is this not possible?

Comment: I have not worked with SVG yet. I'm just saying that, even if it was possible to add SVG images to the canvas, this sole action would not solve the resizing problem. Resizing canvas' is done by JavaScript. Maybe you can use the same technique for resizing your SVG image.

Comment: Why are you converting from something which will automatically resize with the window (SVG) to something which won't (canvas) and then recreating the resizing functionality in code?  Why not just leave it as SVG?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This requires quite some boilerplate code to demonstrate so I'm just gonna point you in the right direction.

Say you have access to a canvas object/element named `myCanvas`. When you execute `var ctx = myCanvas.getContext('2d')` then `ctx` is an instance of `CanvasRenderingContext2D`. Now when you draw your image `img` you execute `ctx.drawImage(img, dx, dy, sw, sh)` where:

- `dx` and `dy` is the offset from the top-left corner.
- `sw` and `sh` is the absoulte size of the image.

So, you adjust the image size with `sw` and `sh`. You want them to depend on the canvas size which you can access with `myCanvas.height` and `myCanvas.width`.

You want the canvas width/height to depend on window size. Window size is accessed with `window.innerWidth` and `window.innerHeight`. When you resize you can listen to this event like this: `window.addEventListener('resize', function (evt) { /* handle resize here */ });`. Example:

```
var updateCanvasSize, canvasRelativeSize;

canvasRelativeSize = .5;

updateCanvasSize = function (evt) {
  myCanvas.width  = canvasRelativeSize * window.innerWidth;
  myCanvas.height = canvasRelativeSize * window.innerHeight;
  draw(); // redraws the canvas since size has changed
};
```