# Resize svg image put inside html5

Tags: html, svg

I have a html5 webpage with an svg picture in it.

when I drag to change the horizontal size, the size of svg image change too, but if I change the vertical size of the browser, svg image doesn't change the size.

Can anyone tell me why that happens?

Comment: You should find an answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8646915/svg-in-html5-canvas-element

Comment: Please post the relevant parts of your code, preferably as a jsfiddle link.

Comment: thank you Erik, I'll see your link

Answer (score 1):

You have preserveAspectRatio attribute which takes care about positioning your image within viewbox. Below is link with SVG figure that showing how those attribute manage position of image.
Take a look at http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/images/coords/PreserveAspectRatio.svg

Detailed explanation/reference about preserveAspectRatio attribute is here: http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/coords.html#PreserveAspectRatioAttribute

Cheers!

Comment: yes, right, these attributes make the svg change the size when window resize. Thank you